# Coq tactic for record equality?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

In Coq, when attempting to prove equality of records, is there a tactic that will decompose that into equality of all of its fields? For example,

```
Record R := {x:nat;y:nat}.

Variables a b c d : nat.

Lemma eqr : {|x:=a;y:=b|} = {|x:=c;y:=d|}.
```

Is there a tactic that will reduce this to `a = c /\ b = d`? Note that in general, any of `a b c d` might be big complicated proof terms (which I can then discharge with a proof irrelevance axiom).

Comment: @Zimm i48 The description for `coq-tactic` says: "Tactics are programs written in Ltac, the untyped language used in the `Coq` proof assistant to transform goals and terms." In my understanding this means questions about how to *write* tactics using Ltac, or questions on proof automation in general. But I admit the description is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: All right, fell free to rollback and let's maybe improve the description? Maybe even change the tag name to ltac? It would be so much clearer!

Comment: @Zimm i48 I've looked at the full description and found out the following: "This tag should be used on questions related to the issues in using coq tactics to derive proofs using the Coq proof assistant." In this case I think your edit fits perfectly. I'm going to (1) edit the tag info to make its usage clearer; (2) create a new tag `coq-ltac`; (3) add `coq-ltac` to some posts to show its intended usage; (4) maybe we should go through all `coq-tactic` questions (there are 56 now) and make sure they are really about tactic-related issues.

Comment: I do not think you need to name it `coq-ltac`. `ltac` alone seems perfectly fine. If you [search for ltac on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ltac) you only get Coq related questions.

Comment: @Zimm i48 All right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `f_equal` tactic, which will work not only for records, but also for arbitrary goals of the form `f x1 .. xn = f y1 .. yn`, where `f` is any function symbol, of which constructors are a particular case.

Comment: I mistakenly understood this as a series of tactics defined for every `f`, e.g. defining `foo x y` would implicitly define `foo_equal`, `bar x y z` would define `bar_equal` and so on. Note for others who get misled: that's not the case, there is a single `f_equal` tactic, the `f` is not metasyntactic in the tactic's name.